# python/kivy: need function clock() but crash because of recursion

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to python and kivy and try to learn from code snippets and trial and error. But now I'm stuck.
To displays weather and garbage information on an raspberry I used kivy.
To grab these information I use the function URLRequest. This function needs the clock-function

```
    while not req.is_finished:
    Clock.tick()
    return req.result
```

So the program works, displays the infos but crashed regularly after some 20 minutes or so wit hthe error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
But I don't understand how I can get rid of the recursion by still getting things working :(

Here's mor of the code in context. Can anyone help?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from time import gmtime, strftime, localtime, sleep

class garbage:
    def garbage_text(garbage):
        req = UrlRequest('http://192.168.1.1:8083/fhem?cmd={ReadingsVal(%22ABFALL%22,%22next_text%22,0)}&XHR=1&fwcsrf=password')
        while not req.is_finished:
            Clock.tick()
        return req.result

class weather:
    def weather_db1(weather):
        req = UrlRequest('http://192.168.1.1:8083/fhem?cmd={ReadingsVal(%22netatmo_M01_00_00_3f_1d_1a%22,%22temperature%22,0)}&XHR=1&fwcsrf=password')
        while not req.is_finished:
            Clock.tick()
        return req.result

class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def update(self, *args):

        uweather = weather()
        aktw = uweather.weather_db1()

        ggarbage = garbage()
        garbagetext = ggarbage.garbage_text()


        self.ids.temp_ist.text = str(aktw)

        self.ids.uhrzeit_top.text = strftime("%H:%M", localtime())
        self.ids.datum_top.text = strftime("%d.%m.%Y", localtime())

        self.ids.garbage_std.text = garbagetext+" rausstellen "

class ControlApp(App):
    def build(self):
        actclock = MyBox()
        Clock.schedule_interval(actclock.update, 1)
        return actclock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ControlApp().run()
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing that loop with `req.wait()`?

Comment: I would suggest adding code to the `update()` method to time it, just to be sure that it takes less than 1 second to return. If the `update()` method takes more than 1 second to return, then the `Clock.schedule_interval()` calls to `update()` will slowly pile up.

Comment: You're code is not indented correctly. Could you please fix this? Formatting is part of the syntax in Python, so it does matter (different indentation = different code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that uses callbacks instead of looping or waiting:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from time import strftime, localtime

class garbage:
    def garbage_text(self, *args):
        req = UrlRequest('http://192.168.1.1:8083/fhem?cmd={ReadingsVal(%22netatmo_M01_00_00_3f_1d_1a%22,%22temperature%22,0)}&XHR=1&fwcsrf=password',
            on_success=self.update, on_failure=self.failure)

    @mainthread
    def update(self, req, result):
        # update the GUI
        garbage_std = App.get_running_app().root.ids.garbage_std
        garbage_std.text = str(result)+" rausstellen "

        # schedule the next update
        Clock.schedule_once(self.garbage_text, 1)

    def failure(self):
        print('garbage failed')

class weather:
    def weather_db1(self, *args):
        req = UrlRequest('http://192.168.1.1:8083/fhem?cmd={ReadingsVal(%22netatmo_M01_00_00_3f_1d_1a%22,%22temperature%22,0)}&XHR=1&fwcsrf=password',
            on_success=self.update, on_failure=self.failure)

    @mainthread
    def update(self, req, result):
        # update the GUI
        temp_ist = App.get_running_app().root.ids.temp_ist
        temp_ist.text = str(result)

        # schedule the next update
        Clock.schedule_once(self.weather_db1, 1)

    def failure(self):
        print('weather failed')

class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def update(self, *args):
        self.ids.uhrzeit_top.text = strftime("%H:%M", localtime())
        self.ids.datum_top.text = strftime("%d.%m.%Y", localtime())

class ControlApp(App):
    def build(self):
        actclock = MyBox()
        self.weather = weather()
        self.garbage = garbage()

        # start the time updates
        Clock.schedule_interval(actclock.update, 1)

        # start the other updates
        Clock.schedule_once(self.weather_update)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.garbage_update)

        return actclock

    def weather_update(self, dt):
        self.weather.weather_db1()

    def garbage_update(self, dt):
        self.garbage.garbage_text()

Builder.load_string('''
<MyBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: temp_ist
    Label:
        id: uhrzeit_top
    Label:
        id: datum_top
    Label:
        id: garbage_std
''')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ControlApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! John Anderson, the req.wait hint worked as well as your reworked code! Thanks!!

Comment: The problem with the `req.wait()` is that it will block your GUI from operating.